# Python Pandas JSON been stuck for days

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to rank riders based on points scored at each race. I would like this to be updated each time a new race takes place and the ranking be based on only the last 3 events.

I'm trying to build one table at a time from my data.json file where I have the data stored in nested dictionaries.

```
{ "1": { 
    "Rider": [ "Fabien", "Rick", "Oleg" ], 
    "Pts": [ 850, 680, 575 ] 
  } 
}
```

I've managed to use pandas to sort the results and give me the top 3 ranking riders as desired, but only when that data is in the script.

when try to build the data from my data.json file I just can seem to get the layout correct.

**What I want is:**

|  | Rider | Pts1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Fabien | 850 |
| 1 | Rick | 680 |
| 2 | Oleg | 575 |

**But what I'm getting is**

|  | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Rider | [Fabien, Rick, Oleg] |
| Pts1 | [850, 680, 575] |

I've searched and searched but I mustn't be asking the right question as Im going round in circles

Comment: Can you post a sample of `data.json`?

Comment: {
  "1": {
    "Rider": [
      "Fabien",
      "Rick",
      "Oleg"
    ],
    "Pts": [
      850,
      680,
      575
    ]
  }
}

Comment: So you just want to read a json to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Convert `data["1"]` to a dataframe, not `data` (where `data` is the result of `json.load()`)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to convert the json to a pandas DataFrame. Try:

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(open("data.json"))["1"])

>>> df
    Rider  Pts
0  Fabien  850
1    Rick  680
2    Oleg  575
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have asked yesterday but I tried and tried to search for the answer. Hopefully now I can merge each event on rider to create a table to rank the riders as I have in my script when the data was in variables in the script.